# How to get from joint distribution F(x,y) to f(x,y) to calculate the marginal distribution of X?

Tags: self-study, marginal-distribution, multivariable

I have this homework question I'm not 100% sure how to tackle.

I have a random vector with joint distribution function F(x,y) and am asked to find the marginal distribution function.

I think need to get to $fx(x,y)$, but I'm not sure how to do this.

My thinking is that I need to differentiate F(x,y) by both x and y,  to get f(x,y) and then integrate over y, but this gets me the marginal density for x.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

EDIT - Thanks Glen. I've switched to my proper user id. It's late here, I'll revisit tomorrow.

EDIT2 - to clarify, the first q in the homework starts at $F(x,y)$ and asks for marginal *probability*. The second starts with $f(x,y)$ and asks for marginal *density* so I'm assuming that in the first instance, they're after a pdf, and in the second, a cdf; to rule out suspicions of casual terminology use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to differentiate F(x,y) by both x and y, to get f(x,y) and then integrate over y,

So after you do step 1 (differentiate over $x$), you have some object.

You then (step 2) differentiate with respect to $y$, and immediately (step 3) integrate it again with respect to $y$. What is the effect of doing both of those things?

Hint:  consider instead the limit of $F(x,y)$ as $y\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Thanks for the reply Glen. From your question - differentiating and integrating cancel each other out. If I slip an x or y into the integration then I get to a density, not a distribution as such - I think this is the case, but this is one of my confusion loci.

Comment: Yes, but the first step is just to avoid doing something useless, eh? The we can set about working out what you really want to do

Comment: Thanks Glen - I see what you're saying and had thoughts along those lines, thinking I can simply differentiate by x (as the F(x,y) is already summed across y) to get to a marginal density for x... and unsure where to go from there. So i'm now thinking I need to differentiate again by x, to get to a distribution.

Comment: Differentiation won't take you from density to distribution.

Comment: I think I might have it now - take F(x,y), differentiate by x and y, then integrate y but instead of using -∞ -> y, use y -> ∞.

Comment: It seems that you're still approaching it the hard way.

Comment: That's highly likely - the long hard way. So if I differentiate F(x,y) by x then integrate by y, from y -> ∞ because we've already got the summation over -∞ -> y baked into the F(x,y)?

Comment: I'm not saying what you're trying to do is right, but there's a much shorter way to achieve what you're trying to do. Take a look at the clue at the end of my answer from the edit a day ago.

Comment: Well, all I can think of next is to ... and this is what your hint directly suggests ... is to integrate F(x,y) over y, from y -> ∞. And do this because F(x,y) is already summed from -∞ -> x & -∞ -> y.

Comment: How do you get "integrate" from "consider the limit"? Tell you what ... back up half a dozen messages or so and go back to differentiating and integrating, redundant as that is. (As long as you integrate over the right limits.)

Comment: You're a patient and generous man Glen, I appreciate this. Ok... so from the paper the joint density is F(x,y) = 1 - e^(-x) - e(^-y) + e^(-x-y)  and *finally* getting your hint evaluate this at y = '∞' becomes Fx(x,y) = 1 - e^(-x) - 0 + 0. So what's confusing me is that this is a CDF, rather than a probability distribution (as asked for in the assignment), which, from the formula in the question, I'm expecting to look like a Poisson distribution, i.e. e^-x

Answer (score 2):

If by *distribution* you really do mean cumulative probability distribution function,
then note that for each real number $x$,
$$F_X(x) = \lim_{y \to \infty} F_{X,Y}(x,y)$$ which is colloquially written as
$F_X(x) = F_{X,Y}(x,\infty)$. On the other hand, if your instructor is being
lax and writing "find the marginal distribution" when what he really wants
is the marginal density, then proceed as above and then get $f_X(x)$ by differentiating
$F_X(x)$ that you just found.